# real time multiplayer google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am using the google play services for a multiplayer game. I am using automatch as the criteria for player selection.I had followed the google sample code for it and avoided switching between activities. I had test it on two different devices and both the users could successfully sign in, automatch and the game would start. However, after some instant both the player gets disconnected from the room and the game state gets destroyed. On debugging i found that the control goes to activity's onPause() method at some instant. 
I came to a solution to have a wake lock or screen on and other to keep a thread running.
I would be thankful for your reply and help.

Answer (score 1):

A problem that I've seen happen frequently is that when you popup up a waiting room UI on top of your Activity and that causes the Activity to get stopped, connection will be lost. I recommend you use our built-in Waiting Room UI which doesn't have that problem, or use an in-Activity waiting message (like a View) rather than popup a separate window.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i was waiting for an answer.Since much time i was figuring out the error. I shall try it and tell you whether it worked out for me or not.

Comment: i used your built in Waiting room UI but the problem didn't end. Can the activity be made a service and then the messages would be send??